# How to enter character by character into a String variable using charAt?

Tags: java, string, char

I want to copy the `String` in s1 character-by-character into the string `finalstring`, using `String.charAt()`.  This code works:

```
public static String Comparison(String s1) {
    String finalstring = "" + s1.charAt(0); // Doubt in this line

    for (int j = 1; j < s1.length(); j++) {
        if(s1.charAt(j) != s1.charAt(j - 1)) {
            finalstring += s1.charAt(j);
        }
    }
    return finalstring;
}
```

However, when I replace the marked line with this ...

```
    String finalstring = s1.charAt(0);
```

... the compiler emits an error for that line: "cannot convert from char to String".  Why does that variation cause that error?

Comment: I can't say I care much for your approach, but your code compiles just fine for me.

Comment: If you want to ask about an error in a piece of code, it is appropriate to present **the code that causes the error.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java (and most typed languages) a String is different from a Character.

`String.charAt()` returns a char not a String.

`""+s1.charAt(0)` concatenates an empty String with a char. The result is a String, so assignable to finalstring variable.

Comment: It's actually fairly common to not have distinct types for strings and individual characters.  Python, Perl, Ruby, and even Fortran are this way.  These are all typed languages, though the first three are not *statically* typed.

Comment: In any event, this does not address the OP's question of why he gets an error.

Comment: @John Bollinger: I think you have not understood the OP question. He is asking : why do I need to add the extra `""+`.

Answer (score 0):

`String.charAt()` returns a char not a String. Hence you have to append `""` to convert it into a string

This does it.

```
String x = 'c'+"";
```

You can convert `char` to `String` also by

```
String.valueOf('c');
```

Comment: Yes, that compiles.  So does the OP's, so how is this responsive to the question?

Comment: "I have a doubt why we used space before entering the first character into the finalstring variable.". He has some doubts on converting char to String in his way. So i suggested the other approach.

Comment: The OP's error is not in fact related to space characters.  If it were, however, a responsive answer would need to explain why.

Comment: Where in the world I said we cannot append a char to a String via the + operator. I am just saying doing String str = str.charAt(i) will give error.